# Why is avformat_network_init() giving unresolved external symbol

Tags: ffmpeg

I am very new to ffmpeg and trying to follow https://gist.github.com/rcolinray/7552384 this tutorial.

i have compiled the library and when i use avformat_network_init(); i get unresolved external symbol  error.

these are my include files and the library.

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
}

#pragma comment(lib, "avcodec.lib")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
#pragma comment(lib, "avformat.lib")
```

and than need to show the compiler

```
  avcodec-58.dll
```